# angularjs generic crud controller

Tags: angularjs

Following the "Wire up a Backend" example from the angularjs.org main page.  Each element of an application could end up with its own a set of ListCtrl, CreateCtrl and EditCtrl.

e.g. for an application with Products, SalesOrders, Users; we have ProductListCtrl, ProductCreateCtrl and ProductEditCtrl; then SalesOrderListCtrl, SalesOrderCreateCtrl and SalesOrderEditCtrl; then UserListCtrl, UserCreateCtrl and UserEditCtrl.

Is there a way of creating a generic set of controllers to reduce the boilerplate code required?  But one that can still be extended if an element requires extra functionality.

Comment: You probably could, but again, it all depends.  If you are handling all the CRUD on a single view, then a service might be what you want.  If you are handling crud in several views, then the controller aspect along with a service might be the way to go.  You may want to work through the tutorial to see the services in action.

Comment: agree with @TimWithers, the tutorial on angular site is well worth the time spent to help get a grasp of various capabilities and seeing how angular helps you avoid lots of boilerplate

Comment: the tutorials do not go into this depth, however I've since found this , which seems to be what I'm looking for http://tinyurl.com/cfvtx5r